# How to call Dynamic Image in Background from API?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to call an Image dynamically from thesportsdb API. [image: See my Code]

After destructuring, I am trying to set the image in the background of this div. But It doesn't show the image. It only works when I add a static image in CSS. It's a react practice project and everything else is working fine.

How may I solve this?

```
<div style={{background: strStadiumThumb}} className="banner-img">
    <img className='img-fluid' src={strTeamBadge} alt="" />
 </div>
```

Comment: shouldnt it be  <div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${strStadiumThumb})`}} className='banner-img'/> ?

Comment: It says expecting a comma. But I don't understand where. Would you please take a look? https://prnt.sc/10ihvzv

Comment: the code below is highlighted properly  as there is `` at the beginning and end of the url() but it shown as a highlight in my own

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Sometimes I feel like I am so dumb and everyone else is a genius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, please add the relevant code directly into the question, not pictures of code. Secondly, `background` isn't a valid `div` tag attribute. If you want to inline the background style, you can use the `style` attribute, which is an object property that lets you inline CSS styles into your element:

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${strStadiumThumb})` }} className="banner-img>
    ...
```

Comment: Perdon me. I have edited the code. The code you have given is not working for some reason. What is the efficient way to show the code?

Comment: @AbidHossain sorry I forgot the background was an image, not a colour. I've amended my code, try it now

Comment: (I'm assuming `strStadiumThumb` is a string containing the URL of the image)

Comment: Wow! Now it's working! You are a genius! Thank you so much.